# Where is my below python code failing?

Tags: python, primes

if the function call is like: `backwardsPrime(9900, 10000)` then output should be `[9923, 9931, 9941, 9967]`. Backwards Read Primes are primes that when read backwards in base 10 (from right to left) are a different prime. It is one of the kata in Codewars and on submitting the below solution, I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback:
in File "./frameworks/python/cw-2.py", line 28, in assert_equals
expect(actual == expected, message, allow_raise)
File "./frameworks/python/cw-2.py", line 18, in expect
raise AssertException(message)
cw-2.AssertException: [1095047, 1095209, 1095319] should equal [1095047, 1095209, 1095319, 1095403]
```

The code:

```
import math
def isPrime(num):
    #flag = True
        rt = math.floor(math.sqrt(num))
        for i in range(2,int(rt)+1):
            if num % i == 0:
                return False

        else:
            return True    


    def Reverse_Integer(Number):
        Reverse = 0
        while(Number > 0):
            Reminder = Number %10
            Reverse = (Reverse *10) + Reminder
            Number = Number //10
        return Reverse

    def backwardsPrime(start, stop):
        s = list()

        for i in range(start,stop):
            if i>9 and i != Reverse_Integer(i):
                if isPrime(i) and isPrime(Reverse_Integer(i)):
                    s.append(i)
            else:
                continue
         return s
```

The Codewars have their own test functions. Sample test case below:

```
a = [9923, 9931, 9941, 9967]

test.assert_equals(backwardsPrime(9900, 10000), a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your code passes the test when run manually. Maybe they range to scan over is set wrong on the test causing it to miss the last one?

```
 backwardsPrime(1095000, 1095405)
 [1095047, 1095209, 1095319, 1095403]
```

e.g. the second parameter is set to `1095400` or something.